# What is the difference between a *surjective* unitary operator and a *bijective* unitary transformations

Tags: operator-theory, linear-transformations

The [wikipedia page](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Unitary_operator) on unitary **operators** states they are *surjective*, whereas the [page](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Unitary_transformation) on unitary **transformations** states that they are *bijective*.

What is the difference between them and when is it correct to use one instead of the other? In my specific case I am interested in unitary operations in the context of quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 4):

You are not reading everything it says. The first sentence says that $U$ is unitary if it is surjective **and it preserves the inner product**. This last condition implies (it is actually equivalent to) that $$\|x\|^2=\langle x,x\rangle=\langle Ux,Ux\rangle=\|Ux\|^2.$$ So $U$ is an isometry and thus injective.

Note that "bijective" implies "surjective".

Comment: But this hasn't answered by question. Why is it that unitary operators are not fully one-to-one (i.e. bijective) as unitary transformations are?

Comment: Ok, what you did not explain is that an injective surjective function is a bijection (https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Injective_function), in which case it seems both are bijective and the wikipedia page is misleading.

Comment: You used the words bijective and surjective in your question, and I was supposed to assume that you don't know what they mean?

Comment: If I had a better understanding of their definitions, would I have asked the question in the first place?

Comment: If injective/surjective/bijective are not automatic and obvious to you, I have to conclude that you are likely not mathematically mature enough to tackle operator theory. No Functional Analysis/Operator Theory book that I know of, defines those terms; they are given for granted, as they belong to a much earlier stage in learning math.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I was coming at this from the perspective of quantum mechanics, in which such definitions are rarely introduced. But thank you very much for making a new student feel welcome to the mathSE community.

Comment: @MartinArgerami no need to be so condescending. If you do a quick Ctrl + F in the standard textbook in Quantum Computing, 'Quantum Computation and Quantum Information', you will see that there are no mentions of the words bijective, surjective or injective.